# Git config list only section names

Tags: git-config

I'm working a project that defines a few custom config settings in multiple named sections.  As part of this, I would like to be able to list all the section names.  I know this can be done by listing all the config settings and reducing the list, but is there any way to directly list only the section names?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible directly without processing the output of `git config -l`.

Note that said output will soon be easier to process, with the addition of the `--name-only` option.

See [commit a92330d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a92330d21c13cf244d8045f5c9d1df6e63893d58), [commit f225987](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2259877531ed2a58ec04aeaeb6beb5183f81f92), [commit 9f1429d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f1429df179adb7a315616d01c9b237b521a3733) (20 Aug 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit ebca2d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebca2d49577665db0318a9c91c0bcca7e4eed963) (20 Aug 2015), and [commit 905f203](https://github.com/git/git/commit/905f2036d0975a828f764947384e732c2908d6eb), [commit 578625f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/578625fa918922713a2ecce2b06611e4566778f5) (10 Aug 2015) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fc9dfda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc9dfda1be25ab3bb311900c6cfbf59d6b6e224e), 31 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## `config`: add '`--name-only`' option to list only variable names
>
> '`git config`' can only show values or name-value pairs, so if a shell
>   script needs the names of set config variables it has to run '`git config --list`' or '`--get-regexp`' and parse the output to separate config variable names from their values.
>   However, such a parsing can't cope with multi-line values.
>
> Help the completion script, and shell scripts in general, by introducing
>   the '`--name-only`' option to modify the output of '`--list`' and
>   '`--get-regexp`' to list only the names of config variables, so they don't
>   have to perform error-prone post processing to separate variable names
>   from their values anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I found it with a current problem, and I poked around on some related questions and I found some easy magic. One slick way to do this is to use `pcregrep` (which is available on the Mac, but I believe it can be had for LINUX). I needed not just to print the section headers, but to parse them for a very specific reason - I wanted to get the names of all the submodules beneath the main module in a project. I thought I could use some `git config` operation to do this cleanly, but as one answerer above put it, you can't. But config files are not magic. They're just formatted text files and formatted text files love being grepped, and when it's a read-only operation like this (querying the file for section header information), it's pretty safe to use whatever non-destructive tool you want on them - `grep` and `sed` come to mind. There are some elegant `sed` solutions, which I will give a reference to, but I like the `pcregrep` one for its simplicity of calling convention. The git documentation tells you where all these files are, depending on whether you are looking at local, user, or global configuration. In my case, I was looking at a very specific config file - .gitmodules, which is normally queried either via specific `git submodule` calls, or via `git config -f .gitmodules ...`. This trick works for any config file of the kind git uses and the git style is not unlike many others.

`pcregrep` is a flavor of grep that uses PERL-inspired regex expressions and, it is more powerful than normal grep for some tasks (like this one). First let's look at what we can do with just normal `grep`. If I call ...

```
grep -E '^\s*\[\s*\w+\s+\"\w+\"\s*\]' .gitmodules
```

I'll get close to what I want. The above regex is a little paranoid and could probably be simplified, but it's like this for a reason, so bear with me. This grep call will list all sections of all types with all instance names, and it will print them out, square brackets and all. The references to white-space is just because I'm not sure how tolerant or variant config files are, so I just want to accept any line that begins with `[<sectiontype> "<instance name>"]` regardless of tabs or spaces or whatever. But in my case, I only wanted sections of type type `submodule`, so my expression could be narrowed to ...

```
grep -E '^\s*\[\s*submodule\s+\"\w+\"\s*\]' .gitmodules
```

Chances are, the questioner also only wanted some section header types as well, so you can see how to make it more and less specific. But the REAL end result that I wanted was a nice bash list of just the names. Here's where the parsing comes in (and I'll bet the questioner wanted some of that as well).

```
pcregrep -o1 '^\s*\[\s*submodule\s+\"\(w+)\"\s*\]' .gitmodules
```

The above does the trick. `pcregrep` calls look pretty familiar, but note that I put the information I'm interested in a substitution group with the parentheses. The `-o1` says "output the first substitution group for line that matches the expression, and nothing else". That's it. That's what the questioner wanted. What I wanted was all that in a list to iterate over, so the line in my script was...

```
declare -r all_submodules=( $(pcregrep -o1 '^\s*\[\s*submodule\s+\"([^"]+)\"\s*\]' .gitmodules) )
```

Now I have an immutable list of the names of all the submodules. Now you may ask why I don't do something like,

```
declare -r all_submodules=( $(git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $name') )
```

The answer is that for my application, I needed to know ALL the submodules that could be inited for this project, whereas `git submodule foreach` only lists the ones that are "current", that is, modules that have been inited. The overall project used submodules for optional components, so at any time, only some were active and inited.

All this wisdom about `pcregrep` did not originate from me. It and some other perfectly good solutions involving `sed` were found on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match) UNIX stackexchange page, which is answering the general question of how to print only the substitution group from a `grep` call. Just like here, the answer is "you can't", but the follow-on has these slick solutions and some others that might match your problem even better. This is a worthy family of solutions to hide in your head, and a pretty essential text-parsing trick.,